# Polylang doesn't recognise content from Duplicate Page plugin

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, polylang

I've got a website written in English, and have added Polylang Wordpress plugin and activated / added German. I also use the WP Bakery page builder to build the layout for the content.

Rather than manually re-build each German page for translating, I used the plugin `Duplicate Page` to copy the English language pages and then via the `Quick Edit` setting in the Pages Overview, I changed the titles, slugs/URLs, and language to German.

Here's where it gets interesting: The original English page shows in the Pages Overview that it has a German version. But the German version does not show that it has an English version.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple.... I have gone into the Page Editor and added the German version to English pages, but this doesn't work for the respective German pages.  (see 3rd screenshot below.)

**Pages Overview**

EN page with German version

[image: EN page with German version]

DE page with no EN version

[image: DE page with no EN version]

**Page Editor**

[image: Page Editor]

Help please?

Comment: Did you found an answer?